# How to interpolate daily climate data using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation

I want to interpolate daily climate data available from 3 locations. I am not sure how to interpolate the data for daily values for 30 years from the available 3 locations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Johan. I will give you a brief overview of my requirement. I have extracted NCEP reanalysis 2 data for various weather parameters and this data is on Gaussian grid. I have been able to convert this data into regular grid using xconv. Now, in order to validate the results produced, I am trying to do a triangular interpolation of the Gaussian Grid data to obtain the data for the grid point as defined in the regular grids. Eg. Gaussian Grid (Lon X Lat) Three Data Point: 47 X 34
46 X 34
46 X 35 Regular grid data closest to our intervention area and also which lies exactly

Comment: I'm not sure; is this a new question or are you working with OP?

Comment: @Paul, The explanation given by Arpaan is not a new question, we both are working together, this is in context to the same question as a response to Johanvdw answer. Thanks
Mamta

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This should have been pointed out, and you should have responded to the answer ("add comment") rather than commented on the question.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer at:
[Interpolation of Three Data Points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5086/interpolation-of-three-data-points)

Rather than interpolating you should first wonder if that is a useful thing to do at all:

> Would your map be better than using the average temperature for the
>   whole area? Unless you know that there is a physical reason why
>   temperature differences occur I would use the average value
>   everywhere, and not make an interpolation. It may well be that the
>   prediction is more accurate if you do that than if you use an
>   interpolated map. Local differences may be causing the temperature
>   changes rather than a large scale spatial trend.
>
> What do you need the map for?
>
> Where is your study area located? Are you sure you cannot get other
>   data for the area?